# azure devops build: BC40056: Imports 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Visual Studio Solution that builds fine on my my local computer.  But when my Azure DevOps Pipeline tries to build it, the build fails with this error:

BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Comment: You probably have microsoft office, installed on your local machine, but not on the DevOps one.

Comment: Yes, I have Office installed locally. I'll look into how to install it on the Azure DevOps Pipeline host.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the namespace or type specified is accessible from your project. And also check that the namespace or type specified exposes at least one public member.

Comment: How can I determine if it is accessible on Azure DevOps?  As I wrote in my question, the solution builds fine on my local machine. So yes, it does export one public member. And it is accessible when building on my local machine.

Comment: Install Azure Devops self-hosted agent on your local machine so that the build is done through this agent on your environment. You can check how to do it from here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: @seitz Not get your latest information, is MoonHorse's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Thanks for checking in!  I decided that I woud first look into switching from a static Imports statement to a dynamic run-time load, so that my code can handle the missing library at run-time rather than at build time.

Comment: @seitz I have the same issue, would you mind creating a quick answer to your own question with what you did please?